# Can I replace the NTMFD4C86N MOSFET with a QM3816N6?

Tags: mosfet

I've got a MSI GTX 1070 with a blown MOSFET ([NTMFD4C86N](https://datasheetspdf.com/datasheet/NTMFD4C86N.html)).

There's a MSI GTX 1080 [repair video on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2V5FhaRzVoM&t=15s). Both are the gaming x model and have the same board layout that had the [QM3816N6](https://storage.ua.prom.st/1683687_qm3816n6.pdf) MOSFET. Will this MOSFET work as replacement?

I've found another that looks ok: [BSC0921NDI](https://docs.rs-online.com/eaf1/A700000009409184.pdf)

Comment: Hard to tell for sure. They look much alike. The difference i can see that might hurt is the gate capacitance. It is higher - meaning you will get more switching losses. How much more? I don't know, might be no problem. I would try and see how much it heats. 

I wonder why do you need to replace it, what happened to the original MOSFET?

Comment: @robertball, can you link the datasheets?

Comment: the original MOSFET shorted  i can see a solder ball next to it and pin 1 reads different from the others there's a repair video on youtube for a gtx 1080 same model the only difference is the gpu the board layout is the same. looking at the data sheet for QM3816N6 the Continuous Drain Current seems higher i was thinking it might have been used instead because the 1080 higher power draw.

Comment: Like i said, it's not only about current capability. There is a driver that outputs certain current. If you use a MOSFET with higher gate capacitance, it will open slower and therefore will dissipate more heat. How significant that is i can't tell before i see the full schematics. Why don't you just clean the solder ball? Are you sure you need to replace the MOSFET?

Comment: I'm not worried about the heat i was thinking the might be a compatibility issue with the MOSFET driver. thanks for your quick reply

Comment: its the same issue as the repair video the 6 pin pcie is shorted and when checking pin 1 on each MOSFET only one is different

Comment: if you think i would watch the video.... and, you should care about heat. if it goes runaway, it will burn fairly quickly.

Comment: @Voltage Spike, sorry i missed your comment. https://pdf1.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/view/1116495/UPI/QM3816N6.html
https://datasheetspdf.com/pdf-file/932366/ONSemiconductor/NTMFD4C86N/1

Answer (score 2):

The overall specs look generally comparable, but if the MOSFET is part of one of the VRM phases (which I suspect it is) then you should try to avoid mixing and matching MOSFETs.

My biggest concern is that the replacement MOSFET (QM3816N6) has higher gate capacitance, longer rise/fall times, different threshold voltage ranges, and different transconductances. I'd be worried about potential shoot-through during switching transients, where your new MOSFET's high side is too slow coming out of conduction while the other MOSFETs' low sides are coming into conduction, or vice versa.

The \$T_{\text{d(on)}}\$ and \$T_{\text{d(off)}}\$ specs aren't *super* far off, but the \$T_r\$ and \$T_f\$ specs are significantly out. This does mean that shoot-through is more likely to occur in partial conduction than in the on state, which does limit the potential for damage, but it still makes me a bit uneasy. If it was just a few percent difference it wouldn't make me raise my eyebrows much, but we're talking about 75% longer \$T_r\$.

This is honestly right on the limit of what I would deem as being *potentially* workable. The problem is that the failure condition is that you blow up your VRM entirely, and possibly take your GPU core with it.

Comment: NorthridgeFix on YouTube replaced QM3816N6 with AOE6930 https://datasheetspdf.com/pdf-file/1086064/Alpha&OmegaSemiconductors/AOE6930/1. He said these two are comparable but Td(on),Td(off) and Tr,Tf specs are out. All 3 seem quite different.    
thanks

Comment: @RobertBall if you are so sure, why do you ask? You have another person explaining you the risks, why do you argue?

Comment: @RobertBall The AOE6930 replacing a QM3816N6 is a far better match than a QM3816N6 replacing a NTMFD4C86N. The Q2 timings on AOE6930 and QM3816N6 aren't actually that different and the AOE6930 makes up for its higher gate capacitance by having higher transconductance, so they end up being quite similar in terms of transfer characteristics. The Q1 timings are further out, but the AOE6930 is faster, and if you're going to have an imbalance it's better to have a single faster MOSFET pair in a VRM than a single slower MOSFET pair in a VRM.

Comment: @RobertBall My intuition is that you've got about a 30% chance of this working in and getting you another year of life from the card. The alternatives are that it totally fails to operate, it'll works unreliably and fails under load, or it works for a while but then pops a MOSFET again and possibly takes your GPU core with it. I can't tell you for sure which of these it'll be. Ultimately it's up to you as to whether you try doing this. I can tell you the risks from a technical perspective, but it's up to you to evaluate those risks against your own risk appetite and choose what path to take.